# How can I compare two different date formats?

Tags: r, date, merge, compare

I want to compare different date formats and set a value. I have two dataframes:

dataframe 1: **test**

```
  head(test)
          number                  date            country
        1   6317004100         2012-10-30                  Italy
        2   6317071200         2013-12-02                Germany      
        3   6317064800         2013-03-06                    USA
        4   6317071200         2013-11-06                Germany       
        5   6317071200         2013-08-12                Germany           
        6   6317004100         2012-10-26                Croatia
```

dataframe 2: **dataframe**

```
head(dataframe)
            date            group
1           2012-07             1
2           2012-08             1
3           2012-09             2
4           2012-10             2
5           2012-11             2
6           2012-12             2
7           2013-01             3
8           2013-02             3
9           2013-03             3
10          2013-04             3
11          2013-05             3
12          2013-06             3
13          2013-07             4
14          2013-08             4
15          2013-09             4
16          2013-10             4
17          2013-11             4
18          2013-12             4
```

I want to compare **test$date** with **dataframe$date** with the rule: 
Everything of **test$date** that is in 2012-07 goes in group 1, everything in 2012-08 goes in group 1 and so on...that I get this output:

```
 > test
          number                  date           country   group 
        1   6317004100         2012-10-30          Italy    2
        2   6317071200         2013-12-02        Germany    4   
        3   6317064800         2013-03-06            USA    4
        4   6317071200         2013-11-06        Germany    4   
        5   6317071200         2013-08-12        Germany    4       
        6   6317004100         2012-10-26        Croatia    2
```

I tried this:

```
> merge(dataframe, test, by.x="date", by.y="date")
[1] date group number country 
<0 rowes> (or row.names with length 0)
```

but nothing happend. Both date columns are factors.

Any ideas what would work?

Comment: you really need to convert dates from strings to date types or ISO 8061 formats, using the locale and then compare date objects. Dates are not strings!

Comment: I agree with Dragonthoughts that it would be best to convert them to date format first. I usually use package lubridate (https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) for this.

Comment: I totally agree with you both, just for some preprocessing steps I needed to convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-merge option would be using `match`. Here we convert `test` to YYYY-MM format and `match` it with `dataframe$date` and get corresponding `group`.

```
test$group <- dataframe$group[
               match(format(as.Date(test$date), "%Y-%m"), dataframe$date)]


test
#      number       date country group
#1 6317004100 2012-10-30   Italy     2
#2 6317071200 2013-12-02 Germany     4
#3 6317064800 2013-03-06     USA     3
#4 6317071200 2013-11-06 Germany     4
#5 6317071200 2013-08-12 Germany     4
#6 6317004100 2012-10-26 Croatia     2
```

---

`merge` option would be by creating a new `Date2` column

```
test$Date2 <- format(as.Date(test$date),"%Y-%m")
merge(dataframe, test, by.x = "date", by.y = "Date2")

#  date    group     number       date country
#1 2012-10     2 6317004100 2012-10-30   Italy
#2 2012-10     2 6317004100 2012-10-26 Croatia
#3 2013-03     3 6317064800 2013-03-06     USA
#4 2013-08     4 6317071200 2013-08-12 Germany
#5 2013-11     4 6317071200 2013-11-06 Germany
#6 2013-12     4 6317071200 2013-12-02 Germany
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one question, what is test**2**$group?

Comment: @pineapple I changed the name. should be ok now.

Comment: Okay, very nice! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`:

```
df1%>%
   mutate(mnt=format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m"))%>%
   left_join(df2%>%mutate(date=as.character(date)),by=c("mnt"="date"))
      number       date country     mnt group
1 6317004100 2012-10-30   Italy 2012-10     2
2 6317071200 2013-12-02 Germany 2013-12     4
3 6317064800 2013-03-06     USA 2013-03     3
4 6317071200 2013-11-06 Germany 2013-11     4
5 6317071200 2013-08-12 Germany 2013-08     4
6 6317004100 2012-10-26 Croatia 2012-10     2
```